# How to have continuous connection with MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp, setinterval, requests-per-second

I have an application in JSP, using MYSQL database and Apache 6.0 server.

**Interfaces** : Admin and Client

**Requirement** : Admin should get all the client names who are logged in. There is one text-box, if admin enters any message in text-box and clicks on any client, that message should display on the client browser.

**Current Implementation** : Once admin clicks on the client name in database I am updating a column named 'status' with the text box value. (Initial value of 'status' column keeping as FALSE).
On client side I have **set interval** method which is calling a servlet using ajax **(every second)** and executing a query which checks the 'status' value, if it's NOT FALSE I have a function which shows the retrieved value on the page.

**Issue** : Due to the one connection per client per second, MYSQL is taking 100% CPU usage and crashing down. I have around 200 clients using the application simultaneously.

I need an alternative and efficient solution for this.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Is PostgreSQL an option? It supports LISTEN/NOTIFY. How about Web Socket?

Comment: Does JSP have server-side shared memory?  If so, you could update that to say that a message is pending.  Or, better yet, record which user(s) have messages pending.  Then, the server does not need to check the database when AJAX pokes it; it only checks this shared memory.  Then, only if needed, it can connect to the database.

Comment: Another approach is to have memcached hold the desired info.